# zerorpc client will stuck after calling an Not exist server timeout for more 1,000 times

Tags: python-2.7, gevent, zerorpc

i user zerorpc to build my rpc program, but i found an interest phenomenon,

#### code

```
import zerorpc

c = zerorpc.Client(timeout=0.1)
c.connect("tcp://192.168.33.12:4242")

count = 0
while True:
    print(count)
    try:
        print c.hello("RPC", async=False)
    except zerorpc.exceptions.TimeoutExpired as e:
        print(e)
    count+=1
```

**
the server above is not reachable, it will kept print timeout message, but over 1,000 times, it stuck in `gevent.queue.Channel.put()`, i had try so many time, the number 1,000 is fixed, but i do not know why?
**

#### output

```
992
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
993
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
994
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
995
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
996
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
997
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
998
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
999
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
1000
timeout after 1s, when calling remote method hello
1001



^CKeyboardInterrupt
2021-01-09T06:12:34Z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_client.py", line 12, in <module>
    print c.hello("RPC", async=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/core.py", line 283, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kargs: self(method, *args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/core.py", line 272, in __call__
    bufchan.emit_event(request_event)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/channel.py", line 234, in emit_event
    self._channel.emit_event(event)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/heartbeat.py", line 116, in emit_event
    self._channel.emit_event(event, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/channel.py", line 154, in emit_event
    self._multiplexer.emit_event(event, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/channel.py", line 66, in emit_event
    return self._events.emit_event(event, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/events.py", line 360, in emit_event
    self._send(parts, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/events.py", line 136, in __call__
    self._send_queue.put(parts, timeout=timeout)
  File "src/gevent/queue.py", line 629, in gevent._queue.Channel.put
  File "src/gevent/queue.py", line 624, in gevent._queue.Channel.put
  File "src/gevent/_waiter.py", line 151, in gevent.__waiter.Waiter.get
  File "src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py", line 60, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
  File "src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py", line 60, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
  File "src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py", line 64, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
  File "src/gevent/__greenlet_primitives.pxd", line 35, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives._greenlet_switch
KeyboardInterrupt
```

any help will appreciated

Comment: I think this is the size of the zmq socket queue behind. zerorpc handles the timeout with gevent. But the zmq keeps growing until it's full. I guess when zmq reconnect you get a storm of requests on the server. Which are all executed. Then the result is dropped since no client is known to be waiting.

Comment: In practice it's not to bad of a problem because it's rare to retry in a loop without exponential back off. If I were to redo it, I wouldn't have used zmq for this application.

Comment: it is true that client will work fine after setting up rpc server. But i do confusing where did rpc client control this, after looking up to the source code of zerorpc-python, i got nothing..